# Error trying to bind invalid credentials

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP server but I am always getting 'Error trying to bind: invalid credentials' when I supplied the right credentials. How do I troubleshoot this issue? How do I know if connection is successful? I am stuck here please let me know if there are any suggestions.

```
    <?php
    $domain = 'school123.edu';
    $username = 'test';
    $password = 'password';
    $ldapconfig['host'] = 'server123';
    $ldapconfig['port'] = 389;

    $ldapconn=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']);
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        // binding to ldap server
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $username, $password) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
        // verify binding
        if ($ldapbind) {
            echo "LDAP bind successful...<br /><br />";

     } else {
            echo "LDAP bind failed...";
        }

     $dn='dc=school123,dc=edu';
     $result = ldap_search($ldapbind,$dn,'(&(objectClass=*)(sAMAccountName=' . $username. '))');

    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
    echo $entries["count"]." entries returned\n";

    // all done? clean up
    ldap_close($ldapconn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Try to bind using Distinguished Name or `userPrincipalName`, which usually looks like (info taken from your code sample): *test@school123.edu*. What do you get...? Also, if you are connecting to AD, I highly recommend taking a look at [what information does Active Directory accept as a username](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223499.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now(bind successful).  what is the right syntax for search query? I am trying to see whether user exists. thank you again.

Comment: I am getting incorrect login with the following syntax. $dn = 'dc=school123,dc=edu'; $isUserExist =ldap_search($ldapbind,$dn,'(&(objectClass=*)(sAMAccountName=' . $username. '))');  Do I have to speacify LDAP Tree?

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect login"? Note, however, that `ldap_search` returns a Result resource identifier - to count how many objects the search returned, you may use [ldap_count_entries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-count-entries.php).

Comment: I modified the original post to have ldap_get_entries. I am not getting anything for $entries["count"].

Comment: The only logical explanation is that the server really cannot find an object with such a samAccountName in this domain. Perhaps you have more domains? Try to do the search on Global Catalog -> change the port to 3268 and do the search again (make sure to authenticate using UserPrincipalName, as described above).

Comment: I looked at AD. The user exists in the following tree. school123.edu -->Head -->Admin --> IT --> Users

Comment: Try to remove the objectClass constraint from the search filter as it is unnecessary anyway. Can you somehow confirm that the samAccountName you are searching for is really the same the user has? Can you find the account by searching for a value from a different attribute, i.e. *(mail=test@school123.edu)* ?

Comment: It still returns NULL. ldap_search($ldapbind, $dn,'(&(mail=test@school123.edu))');

Comment: Does the account you are authenticated with have read access on the object you are searching for...? What happens if you set the baseDN to the OU which directly contains the user you are searching for?

Comment: Yes this account has read access to AD. I have the same issue with the following DN. I have used $dn='OU=Users,OU=IT,OU=Admin,OU=Head,dc=school123,dc=edu'

Comment: Check what `ldap_error` returns **immediately** after `ldap_search`. There might be some info as to what is going on. Besides that, I have run out of ideas...

Comment: ldap_error returns 'Success' and error number is 0.